# Sum up shortest paths in a weighted network

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I have a `graph` with 340 `nodes` and 700 `links`. As for performance indicator of the network, I want to compute the sum of all `weighted shortest paths` in my network.

I tried the `all_shortest_paths` command from the `igraph` package. But my system doesn't have enough RAM to store the resulting matrix. 
Can someone recommend a `package` or `code` which computes the sum of all shortest paths? (So the big matrix is not needed?)
For `unweighted` networks is the command `mean_distance`, which does basically something similar!?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the package [dodgr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dodgr/vignettes/dodgr.html). With

```
dodgr_dists(graph)
```

you can generate a square matrix of distances between your nodes ([more info](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dodgr/versions/0.1.3/topics/dodgr_dists)).

**Note:** This will only work if your graph is directed.